# How to disable camera moves (mouse drag) in an Unreal Engine editor plugin?

Tags: c++, camera, mouse, unreal

I tried to override FEdMode:

```
virtual bool DisallowMouseDeltaTracking() const override
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("do not allow mouse delta tracking!"));
    return true; // I also tried to return false
}
```

but the problem is that the cursor stops moving (and gets invisible).

Is it possible to change the camera moves (to make it like in 3Ds max or sketchup)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update the mouse position in the Render() function:

```
void FPBEdMode::Render(const FSceneView* View, FViewport* Viewport, FPrimitiveDrawInterface* PDI)
{
    MousePosition.X = FMath::Clamp(Viewport->GetMouseX(), 0, Viewport->GetSizeXY().X-1);
    MousePosition.Y = FMath::Clamp(Viewport->GetMouseY(), 0, Viewport->GetSizeXY().Y-1);
 }
```

and I reset the mouse position on mouse release (taken from [FoliageEdMode.cpp](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/311e18ff369078e192a83f27834b45bdb288168a/Engine/Source/Editor/FoliageEdit/Private/FoliageEdMode.cpp)):

```
bool FPBEdMode::InputKey(FEditorViewportClient *ViewportClient, FViewport *Viewport, FKey Key, EInputEvent Event)
{
    if (Event == IE_Released && Key == EKeys::LeftMouseButton)
    {
        Viewport->SetPreCaptureMousePosFromSlateCursor();
    }
}
```